# Getting param of url on dataprovide class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, uicomponent, ui-grid

I am having ui grid, I want to filter the data based on the param passed in the url.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using the default fiter component, you can just pass any value to any of the columns listed in grid.

Comment: No can you give any link to it.

Comment: Please update your code , so I can update corresponding component.